# Auto-converting HTML email to PDF. Thoughts?

Tags: php, email, pdf

A client came to me with an interesting request the other day: automatically creating a formatted PDF from an HTML email. Basically, they send out a nightly newsletter and would like to add a "bot" email address to the list that takes the email, converts it to a formatted PDF and uploads that PDF to a folder on Box.net. The process needs to be done via PHP.

Once I get the HTML from the email, I don't think the steps after that will be too much trouble (I'll probably just use [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) to convert the HTML to PDF, the formatting isn't anything complicated). My specific question is on the steps to take for retrieving an email and grabbing the HTML out of it. Is there a way to set up a mail account where a PHP script is run every time an email is received? If so, how do I access the content of a mailbox and/or email via PHP? Would it be easier, or make more sense to periodically check the mailbox for new emails?

Any thoughts on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: You can use `procmail` or a `cron` job and imap/pop3 polling. Various libraries exist for mail parsing. http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox or http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse email without using Mailparse PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251926/how-to-parse-email-without-using-mailparse-php-extension)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i process incoming mail with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117897/how-can-i-process-incoming-mail-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script called [email2pdf](https://github.com/andrewferrier/email2pdf) which does something very similar to convert HTML (and plain-text) email to PDF. It uses python, rather than PHP, and is designed to work in tandem with [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) to actually fetch the mail.

More information in the [README](https://github.com/andrewferrier/email2pdf/blob/master/README.md).

(sorry for the slight self-promotion, but I think this is relevant).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what to advise without knowing what platform you're using.

In Unix and Linux environments, [Fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) is an old favourite for grabbing mail from a POP or IMAP server.  Once Fetchmail fetches your mail, you can save it to a file, pipe it through a program, etc., and figure out your automation with various conversion tools from there.

If you don't want to have to "poll" your mailbox using fetchmail in a cron job, then you may be able to trigger conversions on the mail server itself.  A Unix or Linux mail server running [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/) or [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) (or other similar software) as the MTA may use [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) as a "local delivery agent".  Procmail includes an flexible language that can be used to recognize patterns in email and "do" things.  If Procmail is delivering your mail, you could easily write a "recipe" for it that would recognize incoming HTML mail that matches your criteria, then pipe the HTML part through a conversion program.  And page somebody, or run some other program, or whatever.

The actual process for converting HTML to PS/PDF also really depends on your platform, which you haven't specified.  Bear in mind that conversion from PS to PDF is trivial in unix environments, so if you find a conversion to PS, you can easily make that into PDF.  Have a look at the [list of recommendations from w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2things.html), or ask for support for your platform.  I use FreeBSD, where [html2ps-letter](http://www.freshports.org/print/html2ps-letter) exists.